# UrlRewrite para nome de fotografia - Web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewrite, url-amigável

Hoje tenha as urls das imagens do meu site como:

*/imagens/tb/1280077_894mvzfxoojqb.jpg*

Gostaria de conseguir renomear isso para que no HTML gerado ficasse

`Apartamento_em_SaoPaulo.jpg` ou algo semelhante.

Opções possíveis.

```
Apartamento_em_SaoPaulo__1280077_894mvzfxoojqb.jpg
```

ou

```
/1280077_894mvzfxoojqb/Apartamento_em_SaoPaulo.jpg
```

Isso é para motivos de SEO.
**Ou seja, No html ele estaria com um nome mas iria buscar fisicamente a foto com outro nome.**

Algo do tipo:

```
RewriteRule  ^/imagens/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).jpg /imagens/$1.jpg
```

Mas não seria viável fazer rename fisicamente nas fotos(tem mais de 2 milhões de imagens), isso teria que ser algo como `Route` ou `UrlRewrite`

Comment: Pode ser assim, simplesmente? `Fotos/1280077`

Comment: Não por motivos de SEO foi pedido que a foto tivesse uma sintaxe do tipo casa_em_Campinas_2_dormitorios.jpg porém essa foto estaria fisicamente salva como 123142342423.jpg então precisa ser um Rewrite para fazer isso. mas não sei como

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Passo 1: Configurando o Motor de Requisições

Em primeiro lugar, você precisa informar sua aplicação que irá tratar requisições terminadas por arquivo de forma diferenciada. Para isso, modifique seu arquivo `web.config`, acrescentando o seguinte:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      ...
      <add name="JpegFileHandler" path="*.jpg" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

## Passo 2: Configurando a Rota

No seu arquivo `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`, configure uma rota assim:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Fotos",
    url: "{foto}.jpg",
    defaults: new { controller = "Fotos", action = "Obter", foto = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

## Passo 3: `RouteExistingFiles`

Isto evita que arquivos que já existam possam ser retornados com o nome original. Você pode comentar esta linha depois.

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Fotos",
    url: "{foto}.jpg",
    defaults: new { controller = "Fotos", action = "Obter", foto = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

## Passo 4: Método do *Controller*

Em `FotosController`, escreva o seguinte método `Obter`:

```
public ActionResult Obter(string nomedoarquivo)
{
    // Execute aqui sua lógica para recuperar o arquivo.
    return File(variavelComAFotoComoByteArray, "image/jpeg");
}
```

`variavelComAFotoComoByteArray` precisa ser um `byte[]`.

Comment: coloquei como certa mas vou só conseguir testar amanha, mas entendi como vai funcionar.